# bootstrap 3 tokenfield typeahead css not working properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead.js, bootstrap-tokenfield

I'm using the [Bootstrap 3 tokenfield plugin](http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/) to create tags for my input. Additionally I'm using the [Twitter Typeahead](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) plugin with witch I'm remotely fetching data for suggestions. The functionality is working correctly, however it is displayed weirdly:

[image]

First, the input is too high, second the suggestions... well, the picture speaks for itself, I guess.

[This](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/blob/master/dist/bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js) is the bootstrap-tokenfield.min.js file I'm using, [these](https://github.com/sliptree/bootstrap-tokenfield/tree/master/dist/css) are the individual css files used (.min), and a click on the download button [on this page](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/) opens the code used for the typeahead.js

Possible version conflict? I checked 3 times and I'm including all the files. Any suggestions?